# dotnet restore fails on linux container targeting private feed

Tags: .net, docker, nuget, dotnet-restore

We've a private nuget feed in our on-premises TFS (using [Package Management](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.feed) extension). We can use it without problems locally and by our Build server. Now that we are playing with Docker, we know that we need to copy a nuget.config with the external source in order to dotnet be able to get the required packages. This file has stored the url and credentials needed and looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="XXX" value="https://xxx.xxx.xx/tfs/xxx/_packaging/xxxPackageFeed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <XXX>
            <add key="Username" value="domain\user" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="password" />
        </XXX>
    </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

We have validated that when we use Windows Containers, it builds successfully. If we switch to Linux Containers, it fails with message:

```
Step 8/17 : RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
 ---> Running in f2b837b36b6b
  Restoring packages for /src/xxx/xxx.csproj...
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.101/NuGet.targets(104,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://xxx.xxx.xx/tfs/xxx/_packaging/xxxPackageFeed/nuget/v3/index.json. [/src/xxx.sln]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.101/NuGet.targets(104,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [/src/xxx.sln]
ERROR: Service 'xxx-dev' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Any idea on how to get domain credentials to work in a Linux container?

Comment: Can you try to change `domain\user` to `user` or `user@domain`?

Comment: Same response for `user` and `user@domain`. I don't know if there is any log that could help...

Comment: Further search seems to indicate that you hit an issue https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5651 which is marked for the future.

Comment: Thanks! Posted a comment on the issue.